# Generic rule interface and persisting rules

Tags: wso2, business-rules, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator, wso2-cep

I am planning to use Siddhi for rule evaluation engine

I have below scenarios to be met

when the conditions are created by user need a way to persist them, which can be used when the node running siddhi restarts due to some reasons

I need a generic interface to represent the rules which are in layman's language not specific to siddhi. Because user should  be able to configure the conditions without knowing siddhi

Any inputs on this will be a great help

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing manually you can create a siddhi query as a template by including placeholders for conditions which needs to be configured. Then for those placeholders so a regex replace based on the values provided by outside.

Almost similar thing was done for Siddhi in old WSO2CEP 4.0.0 by providing a user instance to do the configurations. In this blog i have explained everything in detail [1].

Successor of the WSO2CEP is [WSO2 Stream Processor](https://wso2.com/analytics) which was released recently. It provides a much enhanced Business Rules Manager [2] to provide a generic interface via stored *templates*, that can be created with the Business Rules Template Editor [3].

[1] http://blog.tharik.org/2015/09/user-friendly-execution-management-with.html

[2] https://medium.com/@senthuran16/all-about-the-wso2-sp-business-rules-manager-e7e730b2abe7

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Creating+a+Business+Rule+Template